# C# REST wcf service with https cannot be reached on localhost

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, https, localhost

I am struggling to get a https rest server running on localhost for testing purposes with ms visual studio 2015. The regular http REST Wcf server runs just fine, but when trying to access the localhost through https, it seems to be down (Site can't be reached). I have read the instructions on [the hanselman website](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx) to try to get it working, but I feel like I am missing a crucial step. Is it possible that I am missing a (few) settings?

I am assuming that the creation of the certificate is handled when enabling ssl in the WcfService project properties, is this correct?

Here follows my Web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService.Service1Behavior" >
         <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity"
                  behaviorConfiguration="WcfService.Service1EndpointBehavior"
                  contract="WcfService.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransportSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfService.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfService.Service1EndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The IIS specific server deployment looks like this:

```html
...
  <site name="WcfService" id="2" serverAutoStart="true">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\test\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MyProject\WcfService" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
       <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:2444:localhost" />
       <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44378:localhost" />
    </bindings>
  </site>
...
```

All help is very much appreciated!